# run db2 program usin spool write in cicsweb

Tags: db2, jobs, cobol, jcl, cics

I am trying to execute db2 program(prg01) using spool open, spool write and spool close commands.
DB2 program thet I want to execute, just insert a record into table t01.
in other cicsweb program(prg02) I want to display t01 records.
But when I try to display t01 records old records are shown instead of new records that I inserted into t01 by prg01.
I execute prg01 again and when I try to display t01 records, records that inserted in step1 ar displayed!

I expect that as soon as prg01 executed, changes are updated in t01 table and prg02 displays new records.

Comment: Do you commit your transaction in prg01?

Comment: I think we need more information to help. Wondering why the spool is involved - are you submitting a batch job from the spool using CICS? Do you know that the batch job has completed? Does prg02 get the right data eventually?